# Как реализовать систему блоков на своей CMS?

Tags: php, cms, mysql

Хочу реализовать систему блоков на своей CMS, да вот с теорией проблемы. Не мог бы кто-нибудь рассказать логику действий?

---

Система блоков верстки, например перемещать левый блок (меню) на правый, верхнее меню перенести вниз и тд, управлять в админке блоками сайта.

Comment: А  что же вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: что есть система блоков в вашем понимании?  мб вы имели ввиду модульность?

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить ознакомиться с документацией на разработываемую мной CMS-ку:

http://smart-core.org/wiki/Основы_архитектуры

http://smart-core.org/wiki/Архитектура_(OLD)

Если встретите слово "Контейнер" то это тоже самое, что сейчас "блоки" ;)